# Finding the marginal density function when given a joint density function.

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, random-variables

So I have gotten the following joint density function for random continuous variables $X$ and $Y$.

> $$
> f_{X,Y}(x,y) =  \begin{cases} e^{-y} & \mbox{if } 0 < x < y <\infty \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise.} \end{cases}
> $$

I want to find the marginal density functions of X.
I tried doing the following;
$$
f_X(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-y}dy = 1
$$
Because $e^{-y}$ is a exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda = 1$. However, the answer should be $f_X(x) = e^{-x}$.

I suspect that I am not properly taking the boundaries in account. How can I do that correctly?

Thanks for reading,

K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You know that  $x < y <\infty$. Thus the lower bound for $y$ is $x$ and the upper bound is $ \infty$.
 $$
f_X(x) = \int_x^\infty e^{-y}dy
$$

Then the range for $x$ at $f_X(x)$ is $0<x<\infty$

Comment: @K.Kamal You´re welcome.

Comment: could you explain why the range is $$ 0<x<\infty $$  I posted a slightly more complex but similar question about boundaries and ranges of joint distributions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991255/find-c-in-fx-y-cx2-%E2%88%92-y2e%E2%88%92x-x-0-%E2%88%92x-y-x

Comment: @user1607 To answer your question. $f_{X}(x)$ does not depend on $y$ (anymore). Thus you can remove $y$ from $0 < x < y <\infty$