# find $c$ in $f(x; y) = c(x^2 − y^2)e^{−x}$; $x > 0$; $−x < y < x$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, marginal-distribution

find $c$ in $f(x; y) = c(x^2 − y^2)e^{−x}$; $x > 0$; $−x < y < x$

I know I have to take the integral such that :

$$ \int \int f(x; y) = c(x^2 − y^2)e^{−x} dx dx = 1 $$

but I have troubled to define the boundaries.

**Since $x > 0$ and  $−x < y < x$, can i say that $0 < y < x$?**

I tried solving the following two cases :

**1.**

$$ \int_0^\infty \int_{-x}^x c(x^2 − y^2)e^{−x} dx dy = c \int_0^\infty \int_{-x}^x exp{(−x \times 2log(x))} − exp{(−x \times 2log(y))} dx dy $$

**2.** 
$$ \int_0^\infty \int_{0}^x  c(x^2 − y^2)e^{−x} dx dy $$

but i get $0$ in the integration for both cases.

**Are my boundaries correct?**

**Is this the right approach to find c?**

**How do the integral boundaries change when I want to find marginal densities?**

marginal

$$ f(y) =  \int_{0}^\infty c(x^2 − y^2)e^{−x} dx $$

$$ f(x) =  \int_{-x}^x c(x^2 − y^2)e^{−x} dy $$

Comment: You may integrate with respect to y first, before x.  Another approach is to introduce a change of coordinates and calculate the Jacobian.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I am familiar with the Jacobian, but I don't know how to change the change of coordinates. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 is there any benefit when integrating with y first before x?

Comment: Your inner integral doesn't make sense: x appears as a variable to be integrated, so you can't put x in the upper and lower limits of the inner definite integral.  Jacobian: Rotate the axes by 45°.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's find the marginal densities first.

The marginal of $X$ is

\begin{align}
f_X(x)&=\int f(x,y)\,dy
\\&=\int_{-x}^x c(x^2-y^2)e^{-x}\,dy\,\mathbf1_{x>0}
\\&=ce^{-x}\left[x^2\int_{-x}^x \,dy-\int_{-x}^xy^2\,dy \right]\mathbf1_{x>0}
\\&=ce^{-x}\left[2x^3-\frac{2x^3}{3}\right]\mathbf1_{x>0}
\\&=\frac{4c}{3}x^3e^{-x}\,\mathbf1_{x>0}
\end{align}

Now,

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty f_X(x)\,dx&=\frac{4c}{3}\Gamma(4)=8c
\end{align}

So it must be that $$c=\frac{1}{8}$$

But note that $$-x<y<x\implies x>\max(-y,y)=|y|$$

, so that the marginal of $Y$ for all $y\in\mathbb R$ must be given by

$$f_Y(y)=\int_{|y|}^\infty f(x,y)\,dx$$

Comment: is there a way to determine c from the joint distribution?

Comment: @user1607 The point I tried to make is that $c$ is easier to find in some cases if you find the marginals first. Of course it can be found from the joint distribution.

Comment: yes, that is very handy indeed and the best way to solve this. Thank you. However i would like to understand how to set the boundaries when finding $c$ though the joint distribution.

Comment: i am also not familiar with the notation $$]\mathbf1_{x>0} $$. What does it mean?

Comment: @user1607 That is a shorthand notation for $1$ if $x>0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @user1607 The double integral is also easy but you have not integrated properly.

$$\int_0^\infty \left(\int_{-x}^x (x^2e^{-x}-y^2e^{-x})\,dy\right)dx=\int_0^\infty \left(x^2e^{-x}\int_{-x}^x \,dy-e^{-x}\int_{-x}^x y^2\,dy\right)dx$$